# How to paste code without reformating in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to prevent Intellij IDEA from reformating my code when I paste it.
How can I do this?

P.S. It is needed because I can't customize code formatting for Erlang (ErlGray plugin)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Set `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Editor` | `Smart Keys` | `Reformat on Paste` to **None**:

[image: reformat on paste]

Comment: For some reason I had to close and reopen edited file in order to change take effect (Intelli J 14.0.3)

Comment: Reopening the file doesn't work for me. If I copy and paste some code it not only reformats the code I'm pasting in, it also reformats the code I copied.

Comment: I have had this set to `None` already, but it still inserts spaces around '=', after ':', etc :/

Comment: For PyCharm, the corresponding "Smart Keys" is located under Settings->Editor->General.

Answer (score 67):

In the case anyone else comes across this and doesn't want to change their project-wide settings, I just recently found a "Paste Simple" command (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+V). I'm not sure what version it was added, but it's there as of IntelliJ 13.

Comment: This shortcut is widely used in many applications as "raw paste," even in Microsoft Word. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Or use CMD+ALT+SHIFT+V accordingly

Comment: How to use this shortcut with one hand without cramping?

Answer (score 9):

I found changing Reformat on Paste to None alone didn't work for me. I also had to untick "Smart indent pasted lines"

[image]

Comment: My mistake, I was searching for `Dumb indent pasted lines`. (PyCharm usually gets it wrong.)